# Activity.onProvideAssistContent() example

Tags: android, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow

Could anybody give mi an example of using [Activity.onProvideAssistContent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onProvideAssistContent(android.app.assist.AssistContent)), new in Android 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to [Tajchert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892655/3032209), it's part of the Assist API. I just saw the new documentation for this new feature in Android Marshmallow. It's here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html

With a long press on the home button or saying the keyphrase the assistant  shows a window with contextually relevant actions for the current activity. These potential actions might include deep links to other apps on the device.

This link provides an example of using Activity.onProvideAssistContent(): http://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html#source_app

Answer (score 1):

For example for Music file you will use [MusicRecording](https://schema.org/MusicRecording) type from Schema.org in such way:

```
@Override 
    public void onProvideAssistContent(AssistContent assistContent) {
      super.onProvideAssistContent(assistContent);

  String structuredJson = new JSONObject()
       .put("@type", "MusicRecording")
       .put("@id", "https://example.com/music/recording")
       .put("name", "Album Title")
       .toString();

  assistContent.setStructuredData(structuredJson);
}
```

Full lists of JSON parameters you can find here [Schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/full.html). And to play with JSON without need to compile app - [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) site.